# Reformat JSON file in Python by consolidating text?

Tags: python, json, format

I have a JSON file of the following format:

```
[
{"url": "example1.com", "date": "Jan 1", "text": ["Here is some ", "example 1 text"]},
{"url": "example2.com", "date": "Jan 2", "text": ["Here is some ", "example 2 text"]},
]
```

Which I upload into Python using:

```
with open("data.json") as data:
    data = json.load(data)
```

I would like to reformat the uploaded data so that the text is consolidated and not enclosed by brackets, as such:

```
[
{"url": "example1.com", "date": "Jan 1", "text": "Here is some example 1 text"},
{"url": "example2.com", "date": "Jan 2", "text": "Here is some example 2 text"},
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the "text" field as follows:

```
with open("data.json") as data:
    data = json.load(data)
    for website in data:
        website["text"] = ' '.join(website["text"])
```

Comment: (btw you don't need the space to produce the required output. Use: `''.join(website["text"])`, but the OP wasn't clear about how to `"consolidate the text"`)

Comment: good catch, I didn't notice the space at the end of entry 1 in their list. Thanks!